# 3 or more OR statements are not working in select query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named booking.  it contains a field Rdate, its date of booking. I want to search the booking table by booking month, booking year, and booking date

```
SELECT * FROM booking
  where
   oid=1
    and
   ((monthname(`rdate`)='2021-09-16')
    or
   (year(`rdate`)='2021-09-16') or (rdate='2021-09-16')
```

is not working. The first two or statements are working but the third  `or` statement is not working.

Comment: Please define 'working'. Also please share what do you want to achieve. The expression `monthname(rdate)='2021-09-16'` makes no sense. that function outputs the name of the month (like January) and not a date.

Comment: `year(something)` will **never** be equal to something under the form `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: I doubt the 2 first elements of the `or`s are working, in fact, only the last should be working

Comment: As already said, [MONTHNAME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) doesn't do what you think it does ([example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb0ebe45563fdb99f6d8b971758938a5)). Same thing with `YEAR()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tb1` WHERE (MONTH(date) = 02 OR YEAR(date) = 2009 OR date = '2022-01-09')
```

Use function MONTH() and YEAR()

Search By DATE
[image]

Search By YEAR
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Change the third OR to AND:

```sql
SELECT * FROM booking where oid=1 and ((monthname(`rdate`)='2021-09-16') or (year(`rdate`)='2021-09-16') and (rdate='2021-09-16'))
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `where oid = 1 and (false or false or rdate = '2021-09-16')`, which equals  `where oid = 1 and rdate = '2021-09-16'`.